# How to send internal request from microservice to gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jhipster

I am trying to create an application with microservice architecture and i am using jhipster framework, java, spring boot. In my design my gateway has it's own APIs and i need to use them from other microservices. I can communicate microservice to microservice, gateway to microservice with feign client but when i want to communicate microservice to gateway feign client doesn't work. I can use resttemplate but it's not internal communication like feign. I wonder if is there any way to configure feign client to send internal requests from microservice to gateway.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider your design because having cyclic dependencies is only going to create deployment and maintenance nightmare.Dependencies between services should be reduced at maximum and only in one direction and even more with gateway otherwise you create cycles.

Comment: You are right, i should leave gateway to be only a gateway. That will solve my problem and prevent possible loops.